# How to create an object with specific key and value from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to create a JS object made of specific array values. For example, I have an array `["bananas", 5]` and I would like to convert it into an object `{"bananas" : 5}`. Could you please let me know how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) can be used to create an object from an array of arrays:

```js
let input = ["bananas", 5];
let output = Object.fromEntries([input]);
console.log(output);
```

Where each two-elements array represents a key-value pair from your new object.